# Measure distance from text to bottom margin

Tags: boxes, lengths

I'm making some boxes for providing answers. The box macro takes the height of the box as an argument. I need to measure the remaining space from the line the box starts at, to the bottom of the page.

Consider the following MWE. The first box has the length I want, I need to provide the remaining length to the end of the page as an argument to the second box. How may I achieve this?

(Bonus question: why do I get `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph` error in this MWE?)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{\vrule\leaders\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hrule width.1pt\vskip#1\hrule\kern-\dp\strutbox\hrule width0pt depth\dp\strutbox}\hfill\vrule\mbox{\vspace*{2em}}\\}

\begin{document}
    Please provide the answer in the box below \par\mybox{1in}

    Please provide the answer in the box below \par\mybox{4in}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have `\\ ` at end of paragraph. `\\ ` anywhere is usually wrong. at end of paragraph it is always wrong and will always give you underful boxes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, *you* have `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph. But I see your point ;-)

Answer (score 4):

No box requirements can go without a solution using `tcolorbox`!

`tcolorbox` provides `height fill` option to fill the remaining space in the page.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{example}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=white, 
  colframe=black,
  boxrule=1pt,
  sharpish corners,
  arc=0mm,
  boxsep=0mm,
  left=\dimexpr\textwidth-2pt\relax,   %% 2pt= 2* boxrule width (1pt)
  right=0mm,
  %width=\textwidth,
  height fill,   %% <---- ths fills the remaining space
  #1,
}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{\vrule\leaders\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hrule width.1pt\vskip#1\hrule\kern-\dp\strutbox\hrule width0pt depth\dp\strutbox}\hfill\vrule\mbox{\vspace*{2em}}\\}

%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    Please provide the answer in the box below \par\mybox{1in}

    Please provide the answer in the box below \par\example{\null}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Advantage here is your box can be made very fancy.

Comment: Ooooh, fancybox! I'd tap that!

Comment: I get `I do not know the key '\tbc\sharpish corners'` and `... \tbc\height fill` error when I try to compile your example...

Comment: @Holene Please update `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Done! How can I get `tcolorbox` to fill the width of the line?

Comment: @Holene It is already filling the width, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's too wide. https://www.dropbox.com/s/e40hzpvj3xk942g/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2014.34.20.png?dl=0

Comment: I'll post a new question with an MWE...

Comment: The width of the `tcolorbox` box doesn't adjust to indentation by for instance list environments... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217983/tcolorbox-box-width