# tcolorbox box width

Tags: tcolorbox

In this question, [Measure distance from text to bottom margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215941/measure-distance-from-text-to-bottom-margin/215945?noredirect=1#comment509640_215945), an answer is using `tcolorbox` to provide a box that fills the remaining length of the page. However, when the box is indented by, say, an `itemize` environment, the width of the box is not reduced and the box width exceeds the right paper margin. How may I achieve the correct width of this `tcolorbox`?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcbox{example}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=white, 
  colframe=black,
  boxrule=1pt,
  sharpish corners,
  arc=0mm,
  boxsep=0mm,
  left=\dimexpr\textwidth-2pt\relax,   %% 2pt= 2* boxrule width (1pt)
  right=0mm,
  % width fill,
  height fill,   %% <---- this fills the remaining space
  #1,
}

\begin{document} 
Itemized list
\begin{itemize}
    \item Itemized \example{\null}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 left=\dimexpr\linewidth-2pt\relax,   %% 2pt= 2* boxrule width (1pt)
```

not `\textwidth`